# When do I need a base activity and base fragment?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In lot of examples I see, all the activities and fragments extends from base activity and base fragments. 2 questions:

1. When should I use it?
2. What kind of code should go in it?

Comment: Is normally use it to implement interface, callbacks, etc if you're going to use several "similar" activity/fragment you should go for that "coding style".

Comment: for example lets say you had a navigation drawer fragment that changed as you go through fragments by clicking different links in drawer then you would need a base navigation  drawer fragment that took care of all the initialization and set up

Answer (score 16):

Usually I use a base Activity/Fragment when I need to do some work in some of life-cycle callbacks of all of my Activitys/Fragments.

For example if you use [Butter Knife](http://jakewharton.github.io/butterknife/) (very recommended), you need to call `Butterknife.bind(Activity a)` after calling `setContentView`. So it's better if you create a base activity and extend the `setContentView` method in it like this:

```
@Override
public void setContentView(int layoutResID) {
    super.setContentView(layoutResID);
    ButterKnife.bind(this);
}
```

In child activities when you call `setContentView` at the beginning of `onCreate` (after calling `super.onCreate`), `ButterKnife.bind` would be called automatically.

---

Another use case is when you want to implement some helper methods. For example if you are calling `startActivity` multiple times in your activities, this would be a real headache:

```
startActivity(new Intent(this, NextActivity.class));
```

You can add a `start` method to your base activity like this:

```
protected void start(Class<? extends BaseActivity> activity) {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, activity));
}
```

and start the next activity like:

```
start(NextActivity.class);
```

Comment: Excellent answer

Answer (score 6):

Other activities can extend BaseActivity. If you define common elements in BaseActivities and all other activities extend BaseActivities, then all activities will have these common elements, for example: custom menu, custom bar, design layout or some query logic...etc.

Similar with BaseFragment. I usually log onCreate, onAtach, onPause events in BaseFragment. So I see these logs in all other Fragment that extend BaseFragment. Also, you can very easy and in one class turn-off these logs for all fragment. (useful before publishing realise)

Answer (score -4):

When we need Global error handling we can use base activity/fragment.